# Does this return the pointer to the values or does it copy the values?

Tags: java, object, servlets, pointers, copy

Well OK, I got confused. I believe it returns the pointer to the original map?

```
    private HttpServletRequest originalRequest;
    Map params = originalRequest.getParameterMap();
      params.remove("parameter-to-remove");
      params.put("parameter-to-add", "<a value>");
```

Now are the parameters in the originalRequest going to change after these actions? Or does it just copy the values to params and it doesn't matter what I do with them and nothings going to be changed in originalRequest?

Comment: It's a design issue. What's your functional requirement? Do you want to modify a locked parameter map?

Comment: @Lion I was kind of thinking, this is how filters for ServletRequests are supposed to work? to FILTER OUT the parameters we don't need elsewhere? Did I misunderstand that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not allowed to remove or add any request parameter(s) to the request object. They must remain (as they arrived to the server) until the request object goes out of scope (after the end of the request processing cycle).

Logically, if you were allowed to do something like that, then the request object would not represent the original request any more. During the whole request processing cycle, we want to process the request sent by the client, not the one that has been tampered.

The method you should use instead is [`void setAttribute(java.lang.String name, java.lang.Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: I was kind of thinking Filters are for filtering out parameters from the original request?? I thought this was the purpose to use them if not then what are the filters then used for?

Comment: You can read about filters here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info. They serve different purposes like modifying request headers, security check, locale, etc. Nonetheless, they are also simple Java class that implement the `Filter` interface.

Answer (score 4):

Returned map is immutable Map, that could be the reason why you are not seeing the changes reflected.

As per getParameterMap [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29)

> an immutable java.util.Map containing parameter names as keys and parameter values as map values. The keys in the parameter map are of type String. The values in the parameter map are of type String array.

If you would like to set some value to request, you should use [setAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29).